# What other ports need to enabled in firewall other than 1433 port for connectivity of DB server and CM server?

Tags: 2013, configuration

We are facing an issue while trying to connent the cms server with DB server through CME, issue which we got is based on some firewall settings.
So my questions here is that what all are ports which we need to enabled in database server other than 1433, as right now if we disabled firewall then everything is working fine but if we enabled firewall then we are not able to save anything on DB server through CMS.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at port 1433 I assume you are talking about MS SQL server. According to this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932 Ports in the range between 1024 and 5000 should be open.

Answer (score 4):

If the CME and database are present on different servers , then probably try adding host entries in both the CM and database server.

Port 1433 is enough to contact with the both servers.

Moreover check your MSDTC connections along with that add the port range 5000-5500 [image]